# Spring boot, jdbc template works after manual application jar start, but not via cron. What could be the reason behind?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Im using a spring boot application over Amazon Ec2 which connects to Oracle database.
The application.properties file has following relevant properties-

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true

# dbcp2 settings
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=100
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.jdbc.template.max-rows=500
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-open-prepared-statements=100

logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE

# Schema
spring.appds.jdbcurl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.r.zz.tt:1521/tttt
spring.appds.username = userAPP
spring.appds.password = passwordApp
spring.appds.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

The application jar is run via a cron using root privileges from root folder.

The application has not been returning data for a jdbctemplate query since then.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(lic.skd_es_i.e_g_app_sh_li(key => 54234
, date_from => NULL
, date_to => NULL
, use_country => 'IT'
, work_title => ''
, source => 'LOCAL'));
```

However the same query was working over database always.

Today when I restarted the spring boot application jar by manually navigating to the jar location, it works.

I'm curious to know what could have been the reason behind?

Answer (score 0):

When I started application by manually navigating to the jar location and started application, the query started working.

I then realised that the problem was with the working directory for spring boot application.
The cron started application jar using 'root' as working directory, whereas Spring boot jar was expecting configuration file – application.properties or application.yml – in 4 predetermined locations in the following order of precedence:

1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
2. The current directory
3. A classpath /config package
4. The classpath root

Thus pointing working directory for cron jobs to the correct location (in this case, the spring boot jar location), the datasources were loaded correctly.

Reference- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar